# Xamarin Forms Stacklayout doesn't fill whole MasterPage in UWP app

Tags: uwp, xamarin.forms

I have a StackLayout in the MasterPage of a MasterDetailPage in Xamarin Forms, which has as VerticalOptions "FillAndExpand", but it doesn't fill the whole ContentPage in my UWP app (I don't know, if it works correctly on Android or iOS). In the screenshot you can see a green bar at the bottom left corner.

What can I do to make the StackLayout fill the whole MasterPage?

[image]

Here is my MasterPage:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:prism="clr-namespace:Prism.Mvvm;assembly=Prism.Forms"
                 xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TobyList_XamarinForms"
                 Title="Toby" 
             prism:ViewModelLocator.AutowireViewModel="True"
             x:Class="TobyList_XamarinForms.Views.MasterPage"
                 BackgroundColor="Green">

    <StackLayout Padding="5" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" BackgroundColor="#F9F9F9" />

</ContentPage>
```

Comment: also add HorizanalOptions=VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"

Comment: Adding "HorizontalOptions" makes no difference.

Comment: put the backgroudcolor on the stacklayout

Comment: The background color is just to demonstrate that the StackLayout is not filling the whole ContentPage. If I change the color, it's not visible anymore, but if I add something (like a button) to the bottom of the StackLayout, it is not at the bottom as it should be, because of this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wrapped the MasterPage in a NavigationPage and now the StackLayout fills the whole MasterPage as I wanted.

Now the app looks like this, without the green bar:

[image]

And here is the change in the XAML code of my MainPage:

```
    <MasterDetailPage.Master>

        <NavigationPage Title="Test">
            <x:Arguments>
                <local:MasterPage />
            </x:Arguments>
        </NavigationPage>

    </MasterDetailPage.Master>
```

Answer (score 1):

> What can I do to make the StackLayout fill the whole MasterPage?

You could change the master default behavior. Try using the following code.

```
 this.MasterBehavior = MasterBehavior.SplitOnPortrait;
```

[image]

Comment: This works, but I want it with the split behavior. But thanks to you I tried something else, which works like I want it. I just wrapped the MasterPage in a NavigationPage (see my answer).